# HTTP ERROR 500 after installing child-theme [Wordpress]

Tags: php, server, 500-internal-error, internal-server-error

I just created and activated a child theme and now I'm getting the HTTP ERROR 500.
I've deleted the child theme through FTP and still getting the error.

Also tried changing `wp-content/themes` to `wp-content/themestemp` and that allows me to get back into the wp-admin panel but when I'm trying to install a new theme Wordpress can't create a new directory for the themes.

Is there a way to recover the primary theme?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check `/wp-content` permissions.

Comment: Thanks @MaxYudin. I've set all rights to read, write and execute but still getting the error.
Is there an option to change the active theme through phpMyAdmin or ftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a `500 Server Error` can be solved (or at least be correctly identified) by looking at php logs. If you are on a shared hosting you should have something in your hosting's control panel to check the logs (look for `Error` messages), if you are self-hosting on your own vps you can usually find the logs in the `/var/log` directory.

This said, the current theme in WP is stored as two entries in `wp_options`, which are `template` and `stylesheet`. Name back the theme directory like the original one, write down the directory name of the original theme, and put it as the field value for `wp_options.template` and `wp_options.stylesheet`. At this point Wordpress is, if you haven't touched anything, be in the same state as before you child-theme'd.

Refer to the first paragraph of my answer and edit the answer with the php error so we can look at it.

Comment: Big thanks Fabrizio! As it turned out 'template' was referring to the original theme and 'stylesheet' was referring to the child-theme. I've changed 'stylesheet' to the original theme and it's working like a charm again.